I'm new to react native and stuck with pods issue, please assist
I'm facing issue with pod installation inside of the ios folder of my react native app.
The issue is coming from FlipperKit installation. I've tried a couple of solutions but it dosent see to work
Below are my tool version
Xcode: verison 15.2
Attached is a screenshot of the error. I'll glad to provide any other info needed.
Thank you as you help me out
I tried deleting pos file and reinstalling and also reset my xcode app. All to no avail.

I solved the issue by adding some FlipperKit configuration on the Podfile in the ios folder.
I can't add the full code here, but this short article on Medium is where I got the solution from, check it out. It's an issue with FlipperKit Issue with Xcode 15.3
https://medium.com/@darwinchan02/flipper-bug-with-xcode-15-3-94da2b54ac1f
